# Simple AVFoundation troubleshooting Situation

Tags: objective-c, ios, avfoundation, avcomposition

I have an app that has some video editing tools.  I mix photos and videos and I am running into an odd issue.  When i arrange a video composition with a video, then a photo, then back to the video it plays fine until the transition back to the video at which point it freezes!  I still hear the audio, and if i seek around the video starts playing again.  I dont know how I can error check this!  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you evaluating **ALL** possible return values and `NSError` instances that are possibly filled by the `AVFoundation` methods?

Comment: The only method that Im using that uses NSError is the insertTimeRange: timeRangeInAsset method, and the error i pass is always comes bak nil

Comment: OK, in my tests, my video plays properly if the track i set aside for the photo has at least 1 video asset on it.  So it breaks it if I have transition to or from a video track with nothing on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix more my situation, I created a 1 second clip of blackness and injected that into my composition at the photo spot and now it works fine